# Permutations in python

Tags: python

I have a list of sets and I want to get a list of all sublists possible.
This is what I ve written until now. For some reason it is not including the last position and I don't understand why.

```
def all_sublists(sets):
    l = []

    for i in range(0,len(sets)):
        for j in range(0,len(sets)):
            for step in range(1,len(sets)):
                if sets[i:j:step] not in l:
                    l.append(sets[i:j:step])     
    return l


def fun(sets):
    x = all_sublists(sets)

    for element in x:
        print(element)


    return 0
```

And this is my output:
[image]

Comment: This may be helpful (the source code for the python itertools module) : 
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c

Comment: for j in range(0,len(sets)+1):
            for step in range(1,len(sets)):
                if sets[i:j:step] not in l:
                    l.append(sets[i:j:step])

Comment: @JacobIRR my teacher doesn t want us to use itertools for some reason

Comment: @sonus21  I want to know why it doesn t work this way, I think it makes sense like this

Comment: @DiogoSilva The reason this won't work is because the larger the list, the more time it will take. This has exponential time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the itertools library.

```
import itertools as it

my_list      = [{1,2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{4,5}]
combinations = it.chain(*(it.combinations(my_list,i) for i in range(len(my_list))))

print(list(combinations))
```

EDIT:

Well, powersets are 2^N given a list of size N, hence your formula needs to account for the binary selection process. Something like

```
def powerset(sets):
    pset = []
    for i in range(2**len(sets)):
        subset = []
        for n,keep in enumerate(bin(i)[2:].zfill(len(sets))):
            if keep == '1':
                subset.append(sets[n])
        pset.append(subset)
    return pset

pset([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes:

```py
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add +1 in second loop.  **range(0,len(sets)+1)**

```
def all_sublists(sets):
    l = []

    for i in range(0,len(sets)):
        for j in range(0,len(sets)+1):
            for step in range(1,len(sets)):
                if sets[i:j:step] not in l:
                    l.append(sets[i:j:step])     
    return l


def fun(sets):
    x = all_sublists(sets)

    for element in x:
        print(element)


    return 0
```